# How to double the columns in a data frame in perl

Tags: perl

I have a big data frame that looks like this:

```
    name1   A   A   G
    name2   C   C   T
    name3   A   G   G
    name4   H   G   G
    name5   C   -   T
    name6   C   C   C
    name7   A   G   G
    name8   G   G   A
```

I expect the data frame changed to:

```
    name1   A   A   A   A   G   G
    name2   C   C   C   C   T   T
    name3   A   A   G   G   G   G
    name4   H   H   G   G   G   G
    name5   C   C   -   -   T   T
    name6   C   C   C   C   C   C
    name7   A   A   G   G   G   G
    name8   G   G   G   G   A   A
```

I tried to work with R to do this but the memory limit not allow me to do it. Please help me with a perl solution. I don't know how to write a perl script. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -lane 'print join "\t", shift(@F), map {($_) x 2} @F' data.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

```
perl -lane'
  BEGIN { $, ="\t" }
  print shift(@F), map{ ($_)x2 } @F
' file
```

output

```
name1   A       A       A       A       G       G
name2   C       C       C       C       T       T
name3   A       A       G       G       G       G
name4   H       H       G       G       G       G
name5   C       C       -       -       T       T
name6   C       C       C       C       C       C
name7   A       A       G       G       G       G
name8   G       G       G       G       A       A
```